# MySQL how to count from GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

> ```
> date    | userid | companyid  
> 12.8.14 |   1    |    1  
> 12.8.14 |   2    |    2  
> 12.8.14 |   3    |    1
> ```

I had a table like above. It is easy to count how many company `1` from table with normal query.

My question is : if my query is `select * from table where companyid = '1' group by date`, how can i get `mysql_num_row` equal to 2 for company `1` and `userid` is `1` and `3`?

`select * from table where companyid = '1' group by date` will only return me 
`mysql_num_row` equal 1 and result `12.8.14 | 1 | 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest a query to get the sum of company one entries and then join that nested query to an outer query:

```
SELECT ABB2.*, ABB1.mysql_num_row
FROM `table` AS ABB2
  JOIN 
      (SELECT companyid, COUNT(userid) AS mysql_num_row
      FROM `table`
      GROUP BY companyid) AS ABB1 ON ABB1.companyid = ABB2.companyid
WHERE ABB2.companyid = 1;
```

[Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/311ca/15)

Answer (score 0):

try like this also

```
select *,(select count(*) from table1 where companyid=a.companyid) as count 
from t  as a where companyid=1
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted:

```
select date,companyid,count(*)
from table
where userid = 1
group by date,companyid
```